# Bellman Ford Algorithm Explanation

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I read the Bellman Ford Algorithm. What I couldn't understand is why is there a loop which runs for |V|-1 times (the upper loop in the following segment).

```
for ( i = 1; i <= V-1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < E; j++)
    {
        int u = graph->edge[j].src;
        int v = graph->edge[j].dest;
        int weight = graph->edge[j].weight;
        if (dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + weight < dist[v])
        {
            dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;

        }
    }
```

I went through several tutorials. All are saying the same thing that  There can be maximum |V| – 1 edges in any simple path, that is why the outer loop runs |v| – 1 times. The idea is, assuming that there is no negative weight cycle, if we have calculated shortest paths with at most i edges, then an iteration over all edges guarantees to give shortest path with at-most (i+1) edges.

So, when i=1, the distances I calculated after the relaxation method, are those the shortest distances from the source ?

Please explain this...

Answer (score 3):

Bellman--Ford has two relevant invariants that hold for all vertices `u`.

1. There exists a path from the source to `u` of length `dist[u]` (unless `dist[u]` is `INT_MAX`).
2. After `i`  iterations of the outer loop, for all paths from the source to `u` with `i` or fewer edges, the length of that path is no less than `dist[u]`.

After `V-1` iterations, the second invariant implies that no simple path from the source to `u` is shorter than `dist[u]`. The first hence implies that the path that we found is shortest.

Comment: In the example given in the [link] http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-23-bellman-ford-algorithm/ , in the first iteration the value of dist[c] is 2 ,If we consider the distance from source through all the paths with exactly one edge then the dist[c] should be 4. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3428090 `dist[u]` is at most the length of the shortest `i`-edge path to `u`, but it may be less.

Comment: So, if i=1, the shortest path from A to C is 4. Right?

Comment: @user3428090 Yes, the shortest path from A to C with at most one edge has length 4. That's not what `dist[C]` is at the end of the iteration where `i=1`.

Comment: But as you stated in your point 2, it is 4. The dist[C] is 2 when it traverses from A to C via B, that is, 2 edges.

Comment: @user3428090 No, I most certainly did not state that. It's a one-sided bound.

Comment: I guess I am still unable to get this. Will you explain me the steps happening in that example?

Comment: @Richa Tibrewal Maybe a bit late to comment, but I write for those who are reading this late. In the example case above, as you said dist[C] with path length <= 1, is indeed 4. After 1 iteration dist[C] = 2. What David Eisenstat said in his second point is that the distance between source and C with a path length <= 1 is no less than dist[C] i.e., !(4 < 2) or 4 >= 2 must be true, which is. Hope you see the point now...

Answer (score 0):

Bellman ford vs Dijkstra

1. Bellman also work for negative weighted graph while Dijkstra work only for positive weighted graph.
2. Bellman has TC O(V*E) which is greater than the TC of Dijkstra i.e. O(V+E).

- Steps of Bellman ford:-

1. Firstly we initialize an distance array with very large default value.
2. the array value of source is set to 0.
3. First try to find the shortest path in first iteration.
4. Now, again traverse all node and try to do the same as we did in 3rd step if we again we find new shortest path then negative cycle is present.

The idea of step 4 is, step 3 guarantees the shortest distances if the graph doesn’t contain a negative weight cycle. If we iterate through all edges one more time and get a shorter path for any vertex, then there is a negative weight cycle.